# nvd3 angularjs fixed tooltip

Tags: d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

I'm trying to fix the graph but the tooltip is not fixed and have strange behavior where the tooltip start to float around the window.

I have tried to put in the nvd3.css the position fixed but didn't work:

```
.nvtooltip {
    **position: fixed;**
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.0);
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    z-index: 10000;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: How do you fix the graph? need more info.

Comment: i set a div that covers the graph and set it to position:fixed;

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `fixedTop` option of `nv.models.tooltip` model. This is inside the `interactiveLayer` chart option. So, you can set this up like:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true) //required                      
        ...

    //shoud be separated
    chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.fixedTop(100) //fixed distance from top  

    ...
})
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krispo1/HLKay/)

---

Additional `tooltip` options (from the source):

```
content = null    //HTML contents of the tooltip.  If null, the content is generated via the data variable.
data = null     // Tooltip data. If data is given in the proper format, a consistent tooltip is generated.
gravity = 'w'   //Can be 'n','s','e','w'. Determines how tooltip is positioned.
distance = 50   //Distance to offset tooltip from the mouse location.
snapDistance = 25   //Tolerance allowed before tooltip is moved from its current position (creates 'snapping' effect)
fixedTop = null //If not null, this fixes the top position of the tooltip.
classes = null  //Attaches additional CSS classes to the tooltip DIV that is created.
chartContainer = null   //Parent DIV, of the SVG Container that holds the chart.
tooltipElem = null  //actual DOM element representing the tooltip.
position = {left: null, top: null}      //Relative position of the tooltip inside chartContainer.
enabled = true  //True -> tooltips are rendered. False -> don't render tooltips.
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, i tryed but didn't work, i have read that this case is not implemented in d3 so i don't think i can do an easy approach.

Comment: @krispo will nvd3 support touch events in the future? i'm building an app with ionic framework but on smartphone touch events behaves like onmouseover event